# Is there a local server that can be limited to a specific baud rate?

Tags: windows

In order to make a local web server simulate a real server's connection with a client, I need to limit its bandwidth to a real-world internet value, instead of having the client loading my web-app instantly -which is of no use for loading-speed optimizations.

Given the above, I was surprised to find out that the http server from node.js doesn't have such a simple and useful command to limit the local connection!  (I bet it wouldn't take more than a couple of lines of code...).

So, is there any other local server that can do this? (preferably a free and simple one).

Comment: AFAIR there was a mod_bandwidth (or similar) for Apache.

Comment: Can you tweak Quality of Service on the connection?